# Boolean Flag falsey sustainability

Tags: c#, validation, csv, import

I have a situation where I am importing a CSV file.

It can have an unknown number of columns (which I have accounted for).

But it seems that when I validate the columns, the row validation is reset upon ever new row being processed, which is causing the final process to execute, which if a single row is invalid, the whole process should fail.

#### Process Design:

```
bool valid = true;
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
...
  bool rowValid = true;
  ...
  for(colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
    //Example of a validator
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns[colIndex])){
      rowValid |= false;
    } else {
      //Save value
    }
  }
  
  if(rowValid){
    //Process some more
  } else {
    //Store information for Invalid Values reporting
  }

  valid |= rowValid
}

if(valid){
  //Save all information imported
} else {
  //Show Invalid values and abort save operations
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this will cause `valid = true` when i purposely inject invalid values to verify that the falsey is being passed through?

Comment: `rowValid |= false;` – this is a nonsense statement.

Comment: Why not just `if(!rowValid) valid = false;` and `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns[colIndex])){ rowValid = false; }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `valid |= rowValid` line should be `valid &= rowValid` instead.

Comment: And `rowValid |= false;` should be `rowValid = false;`

Comment: It's the basic difference between OR and AND. The former sets `valid` to true if `rowValid` is true, and makes no change otherwise. The latter sets `valid`to false if `rowValid`is false, and makes no change otherwise.

Comment: `valid |= rowValid` is equal to `valid = valid | rowValid`. If `valid` is ever true, then you'll never assign false to it - `true | false` is always true.

Comment: @Medinoc ok, im usually a VB developer, and dabble in C#, so had a more experienced C# developer advise me on that assignment.

Comment: @GoldBishop: Write "-1" on a postit note and go stick it on that other developer for me would you? ;-)

Comment: i would if i could, hes a SR to me in c#, i advise him on BIDS/VB/MSSQL though, so its tit for tat with us.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly,

```
rowValid |= false;
```

does nothing whatsoever. You probably should use

```
rowValid = false;
```

Secondly,

```
valid |= rowValid
```

should be

```
valid &= rowValid
```

Thirdly, given that you want the whole thing to be invalid if one thing is invalid, you could short-circuit with an early return if an error is detected.

Comment: yeah but they want full reporting not incremental reporting.  So i am storing a collection of rows and the invalid columns and then spitting them out to a Validation Summary like control.

Comment: And "they" are wise. It's infuriating when you correct all errors your application shows you, and re-run the process only for more errors to show up.

Comment: @GoldBishop Ah ok, then you can't early return. Fair enuff! :)

Comment: yeah, it is.  Unfortunately, my validation summary is all in a label.  As its a File Upload don't have numerous fields to put a customvalidator and then plop a validationsummary control onto.  But oh well, they make the request, i full.  With i was genie and could only grant 3 wishes and then they get what i give ;)